# Changing default APK output to include version in the name using MSBuild

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, apk, visual-studio-2019

when building an APK using MSBuild I would like to change the output apk name to include the version number

so

> android:versionName="3.1.5"

would end up like:

> MyAndroidApp-3.1.5.apk

i tried to do a post-build step where i try to copy the apk to a different name , but there aren't any macros in the post build step that has the version (that i can see)

When calling

```
MSBuild .\trunk\TaxiTabletUniversal.Droid.MyAndroidProject /t:SignAndroidPackage  /p:Configuration=Release
```

the output apk ends up with the name:

> company_name.mypackage_name-Signed.apk

In the Android Package Signing setting i can only specify the keystore and paswords, but no output name.

I would like the output name to pickup the versionName in the

> AndroidManifest.xml

file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Changing default APK output to include version in the name using
>   MSBuild

Sorry but the answer could be negative, as I know MSBuild itself doesn't have the ability to read data like Version-number from `AndroidManifest.xml`. In other words, it's not supported by msbuild.

MSBuild can access any [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019) defined in project file or imported targets file, but it can't access `AndroidManifest.xml` file. And there's no official [msbuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-tasks?view=vs-2019) can to this for us, so if you do need this behavior, we have to code ourselves to read the version info from that xml file. Topics about this: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c), [two](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/307548/how-to-read-xml-from-a-file-by-using-visual-c), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47742118/read-an-xml-file-line-by-line-and-add-to-a-list)...(Too many topics online talk about this, so I don't talk too much here, if you meet some issue about coding that, let me know:-
))

Here're two possible ways after that coding:

1.Create a `.exe` file with code to execute the renaming job, and call the .exe in a post-build event

2.Write a [custom task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/task-writing?view=vs-2019) named CustomTask, and add this script into the project file to call this task after `build` or `SignAndroidPackage` target.

```
  <UsingTask TaskName="CustomTask.CustomTask"
        AssemblyFile="path\CustomTask.dll"/>

  <!--Maybe it should be AfterTargets="SignAndroidPackage"-->
  <Target Name="CustomTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
    <CustomTask/>
  </Target>
```

May it makes some help.